# Send all Tokens and Eth to a Address automatically

Tags: ethereum, erc20

I have few child wallets and a parent wallet. Whenever these child wallets get incoming ERC20 tokens or ETH. I want to send them automatically to the parent wallet.

I know I can do below to send the entire eth balance.

```
beneficiary.transfer(this.balance);
```

How can I do it for erc20 tokens.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
require(token.transfer(beneficiary, token.balanceOf(this)));
```

where `token` is the ERC20 token you're transferring. E.g.:

```
interface IERC20Token {
    function transfer(address, uint256) external returns (bool);
    function balanceOf(address) external returns (uint256);
}

contract Foo {
    IERC20Token token = IERC20Token(0x123abc...);

    function doit(address beneficiary) public {
        require(token.transfer(beneficiary, token.balanceOf(this)));
    }
}
```